# Finding a number from a string with ending and non ending values

Tags: java, regex

I have a string such as this: Two examples below.

```
?dtg=6&reqp=1&reqr=
?dtg=654&reqp=1&reqr=
?dtg=785
```

I want to fetch the number after `dtg`.

So in case 1 I want `6` and in case 2 I want `654` and in case 3 I want `785`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String#repaceFirst`

```
String repl = string.replaceFirst("\\?dtg=(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Expression) (regex):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[&?]dtg=([0-9]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
if(matcher.find()) {
    int dtg = Integer.parseInt( matcher.group(1) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in case `dtg` isn't the first url parameter.

```
dtg=(.*?)(?:&|$)
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/qM0xV2

Answer (score 0):

Though using a regular expression would help in most of the cases, to me you have an example of query string from the `URL` - if this is a case I would convert that query string into `Map<String, List<String>>` and then get the value of `dtg` key (that will take care of such case:
?dtg=6&reqp=1&dtg=121212&reqr=
)